# Rearranging the outputs of SVD to correspond to diagonal blocks of the input

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, permutation, svd

### Motivation

I want to perform SVD on `M` separate problems of potentially different sizes. The sizes of the datasets (matrices) to decompose are `N_M⨯2`, where `N_M` is different for each of the `M` problems and `∀M, N_M > 2`.

### Possible approaches

An obvious way to do this is through a {potentially parallelized} loop, where each dataset is fed into SVD separately and the results are handled separately as well.

Another possibility is to arrange the different datasets as diagonal blocks in a {potentially sparse} matrix, then call SVD **exactly once**, thereby vectorizing the computation and having to deal with only a single set of outputs. **This is the approach I would like to focus on in the question**.

### Problem

The common implementations of SVD (e.g. MATLAB's and Numpy's) sort the outputs (columns/rows) of the `U` and `V` matrices according to the magnitude of singular values (`S`). This auto-sorting is detrimental for our block-diagonal case since the association between the singular values/vectors and the blocks that generated them is lost. For [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4560975/3372061),

```matlab
%% Define matrices to decompose:
A = [1, 1, 2; 
     2, 1, 3];
B = [1, 2;
     2, 1];
M = blkdiag(A,B);
%{
M =
     1     1     2     0     0
     2     1     3     0     0
     0     0     0     1     2
     0     0     0     2     1
%}
%% Apply SVD
[Ua, Sa, Va] = svd(A, 'econ');
[Ub, Sb, Vb] = svd(B, 'econ');
[Um, Sm, Vm] = svd(M, 'econ');

%{
Ua =                   #  Ub =                  #  Um =
   -0.5449   -0.8385   #     -0.7071   -0.7071  #     -0.5449         0         0   -0.8385
   -0.8385    0.5449   #     -0.7071    0.7071  #     -0.8385         0         0    0.5449
                       #                        #           0   -0.7071    0.7071         0
                       #                        #           0   -0.7071   -0.7071         0
                       #                        #  
Sa =                   #  Sb =                  #  Sm =
    4.4552         0   #    3.0000         0    #      4.4552         0         0         0
         0    0.3888   #           0    1.0000  #           0    3.0000         0         0
                       #                        #           0         0    1.0000         0
                       #                        #           0         0         0    0.3888
                       #                        #
Va =                   #  Vb =                  #  Vm =
   -0.4987    0.6465   #     -0.7071    0.7071  #     -0.4987         0         0    0.6465
   -0.3105   -0.7551   #     -0.7071   -0.7071  #     -0.3105         0         0   -0.7551
   -0.8092   -0.1087   #                        #     -0.8092         0         0   -0.1087
                       #                        #           0   -0.7071   -0.7071         0
                       #                        #           0   -0.7071    0.7071         0
%}
```

Note how `Um`, `Sm` and `Vm` have the same values as `{Ua, Ub}`, `{Sa, Sb}` and `{Va, Vb}`, accordingly, but the values originating from `A` are not grouped together in any of the decompositions of `M`.

If so, **how can we rearrange ("unsort") `Um`, `Sm`, and `Vm` such that they correspond to the input blocks?** After reorganization, the expected result is:

```matlab
% If M = blkdiag(A, B), we want (up to sign indeterminacy):
Um == blkdiag(Ua, Ub);
Sm == blkdiag(Sa, Sb);
Vm == blkdiag(Va, Vb);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36801447/3372061), this should be possible using a graph approach. Below is a basic implementation of the procedure described in the linked answer:

```matlab
function [row_perms, col_perms, PL, PR] = block_diagonalize(A)
    % Find the permutation of rows/columns of any rectangular array A such 
    % that it becomes block-diagonal.
    %
    % Assumptions:
    %  1) The input is block-diagonalizeable.
    %  2) The input has no all-zero rows or columns.
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %% Find connected components
    nnz = sparse(A ~= 0);
    [nr, nc] = size(A);
    connectivity = [zeros(nr, 'logical'), nnz;
                    nnz.',                zeros(nc, 'logical')];

    G = graph(connectivity, ["r" + (1:nr), "c" + (1:nc)]);
    [comp, ~] = G.conncomp; % compare: comp = conncomp(G,'OutputForm','cell');
    %% TODO: Compare the 2nd output of `conncomp` to a new "block size" input    
    
    %% TODO: Add handling of zero rows/columns to the ordering
    if max(comp) > min(nr, nc)
        warning("No all-zero rows/columns allowed! An additional " + ...
            "invocation of this function will be needed.")
    end
    
    %% Get the sorting permutations:
    row_order = comp(1:nr);
    col_order = comp(nr+1:end);
    
    if issorted(row_order) && issorted(col_order)
        % No reordering necessary
        row_perms = row_order;
        col_perms = col_order;
        return
    end

    [~, row_perms] = sort(row_order);
    [~, col_perms] = sort(col_order);    
    
    %% Build the bidirectional permutation matrices
    if nargout > 2
        PL = sparse(1:nr, row_perms, ones(nr, 1), nr, nr);
        PR = sparse(col_perms, 1:nc, ones(nc, 1), nc, nc);
        % PL * A * PR
    end
end
```

Let's see how this works for the problem in the question:

```matlab
% We assume that [Um, Sm, Vm] have already been computed.
[urp, ucp, upl, upr] = block_diagonalize(Um);
[vrp, vcp, vpl, vpr] = block_diagonalize(Vm);
%{
>> upl * Um * upr

ans =
   -0.5449   -0.8385         0         0
   -0.8385    0.5449         0         0
         0         0   -0.7071    0.7071
         0         0   -0.7071   -0.7071

>> vpl * Vm * vpr

ans =
   -0.4987    0.6465         0         0
   -0.3105   -0.7551         0         0
   -0.8092   -0.1087         0         0
         0         0   -0.7071   -0.7071
         0         0   -0.7071    0.7071

>> assert(isequal(ucp, vcp)); d = diag(Sm); diag(d(ucp))

ans =
    4.4552         0         0         0
         0    0.3888         0         0
         0         0    3.0000         0
         0         0         0    1.0000

>> norm(M - (upl * Um * upr)*diag(d(ucp))*(vpl * Vc * vpr).')

ans =
   8.8818e-16
%}
```

---

Sidenote: if the sizes of all matrices are the same, the [`pagesvd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pagesvd.html) function (introduced in R2021b) can be used to conveniently vectorize this computation. This function requires no toolboxes for CPU computations.